# How to get the solution of (\alpha Z-\ Omega) from the following two equations?

Tags: quadratics

I have the following two equations
$$-\frac{\gamma+2P}{1+2Z}[Z^2+(\alpha Z-\Omega)^2]+2(P-\gamma  z)[Z+\alpha(\alpha Z-\Omega)]=0$$ (1)
$$2Z[-2\gamma_1\frac{\gamma+2P}{1+2Z}Z+Z^2+(\alpha Z-\Omega)^2]-2\gamma_1^2 \frac{\gamma+2P}{1+2Z}[-\frac{\gamma+2P}{1+2Z}Z+P-\gamma Z]-\gamma_1 2(P-\gamma Z)[-Z+\alpha(\alpha Z-\Omega)]=0$$       (2)

How to get the solution for $$(\alpha Z-\Omega)$$ from these two equations?